# How to remap all ctrl+k chords at once in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to remap all chords at once that use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> as the first keypress action?

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to delete rest of the line. Since it conflicts with the most common chord used in vscode, remapping shortcut by shortcut would be inconvenient.

Comment: "Chords" are sets of keys that must be all pressed simultaneously to trigger an action. The name comes from musical chords - many notes played simultaneously. `ctrl`+`k`, on its own, is a chord. What you're describing, where you press the *chord* `ctrl`+`k`, then release the keys, then press another key (or another chord), is a *sequence* of key presses - one after the other, in serial, not parallel. The nicest name for this would be **"arpeggio"** :) Like VSCode, Vim uses one common button/chord as the first key for many editor-related keybinds; it calls the first keypress the "leader".

Comment: That terminology came from vscode documentation: _"Chords (two separate keypress actions) are described by separating the two keypresses with a space. For example, `Ctrl`+`K` `Ctrl`+`C`"_ ([link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules)). It seems they consider `Ctrl`+`k` as one "note" in the chord, even though `k` is not pressed simultanously with`c`. One can still consider the keys being "played simultaneously" to form the action, maybe that was their analogy. I guess arpeggio ("broken chord") was not as intuitive and they went with chord  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a workflow that you could use:

1. Click Gear icon/KeyBoard Shortcuts
2. Click "...open and edit keybindings.json"
3. In the left panel with cursor focus - readonly - search for `({.*ctrl\+k.*},)|({.*ctrl\+k.*\n\s+.*},)`
   with the regex option chosen.  You should get about 57 matches found.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> will select all matches.
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy all those.
6. Shift cursor focus to right panel - keybindings.json - and paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> clipboard to end of file.
7. Now you can find/replace those ctrl+k's to whatever you want.

I have no doubt that that regex in step 3 could be simplified, the problem being sometimes there is a newline and "when" modifiers on a second line of the command. Perhaps someone else could help there.

Comment: Currently it should be: `(\{.*ctrl\+k.*\},)|(\{.*ctrl\+k.*\n\s+.*\},)`

Comment: where do i find the ... in step 2?

ah it's not ... it's the file edit icon highlighted  https://imgur.com/7J8obvQ